# CommandError: /code/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to run linux docker on windows and getting this error.

build was fine.

```
'''
$ docker-compose build
Building web
Step 1/11 : FROM python:3
 ---> 42d620af35be
Step 2/11 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b43065732d6e
Step 3/11 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f65e0da9e14
Step 4/11 : RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2a9d7445a991
Step 5/11 : RUN easy_install pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5994e6452e09
Step 6/11 : RUN mkdir /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0eaa870fb98
Step 7/11 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> af78d4b35f26
Step 8/11 : RUN pip uninstall django
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 92f983bfef88
Step 9/11 : COPY requirements.txt /code/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3c0031987286
Step 10/11 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3915127d3d58
Step 11/11 : COPY . /code/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> de872685c733
Successfully built de872685c733
Successfully tagged djangoproject_web:latest
'''
```

but when i run compose up.. i see below error.

```
'''
$ docker-compose up
Creating djangoproject_web_1 ... done
Attaching to djangoproject_web_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  |
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  |
web_1  | You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
web_1  | Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
web_1  | July 23, 2019 - 03:21:21
web_1  | Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'composeexample.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://case.xxxxxx.com:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | Error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
djangoproject_web_1 exited with code 1
'''
```

and if i try this

```
'''
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .
'''
```

it says

```
'''
CommandError: /code/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files
'''
```

my Dockerfile is

```
'''
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev
RUN easy_install pip
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip uninstall django
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
COPY . /code/
'''
```

my docker-compose.yml is
'''
    version: '3'

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver case.xxxxxx.com:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

'''
How can i fix the problem with composeexample? it is not even created (cause i can't see it in the folder).. your advice please.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the docker client of Ubuntu Windows Subsystem. This gives issues with Volume feature of docker.
Run the `docker run` command on windows powershell and this issue will not come.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if you try to create another project in a single virtual environment. To remove error and create next project delete "manage.py file" which is the file automatically created while starting project.
If you still get error delete the virtual environment and delete manage.py

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 conflicting/overwriting statements:

In your Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /code/
```

in your docker-compose.yml:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

I suggest you remove the COPY statement from the Dockerfile and re-run your containers using docker-compose.

Also, you can remove the RUN command here:

```
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
```

It is not an error, but WORKDIR already creates the folder if it doesn't exist anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is, you are trying to create a project that is already created by re-running the command

```
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .
```

Just run

```
docker-compose run web
```